# How to find not inserted/skipped rows when using waterline's model.create/createEach

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, waterline

I am in a problem that I've to create 10K documents. Obviously I can't do one by one so I created an array of documents and use it like this

```
let arr = [
  { username: "admin", password: "asdasdas", id_ref: "2" },
  { username: "admin2", password: "asdasdas", id_ref: "3" },
  { username: "admin3", password: "asdasdas", id_ref: "3" },
  { username: "admin9", password: "asdasdas", id_ref: "3" },
  { username: "admin7", password: "asdasdas", id_ref: "3" },
  { username: "admin6", password: "asdasdas", id_ref: "3" },
  { username: "admin5", password: "asdasdas", id_ref: "3" },
]
User.createEach(arr).exec(function (err, res) {
  console.dir(err)
})
```

but the problem is that I've unique constraint on `username`. So if the a user is already there it won't duplicate.
**Solutions I tried**

1. I used a for loop and first I used User.find to get the user if not then insert. But it took like 10 minutes to create 1400 documents and skip 1300 which already existed. So this is not optimal solution.
2. I tried the above example way but then I dont know which document is create and which is skipped as in error I see just it's related to just one document.
   **Example Error**:

   ```
   { username:[ { rule: 'unique',
         value: 'admin',
         message: 'A record with that `username` already exists (`admin`).' } ] }
   ```

But I expected array of errors of the documents which isn't inserted.

Is there any way arround my problem? If i can find the skipped rows It'll be a great solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use async lib method eachSerie to loop over your array https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#eachSeries and use waterline method findOrCreate https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/find-or-create

Comment: Waterline findOrCreate runs two separate query i.e. one for find and another for create so that's basically same. I'm using generators so I can pause the execution until findOrCreate completes so it's similar to async eachSeries.